# Do .NET GUI components support HTML (like Java swing does)?

Tags: java, .net, html, winforms, swing

[HTML can be used in Java swing GUI components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), like `JTextBox`, `JButton`, ... etc.

Is there an equivalent to that in .NET (C#) WinForms? Or at least some simple way of making a single word **bold** inside a textbox without using another GUI component?

Comment: In Swing you shouldn't really use this, too since it seriously gets in the way with many Look and Feels. Definitely not very fun and what they support of HTML is basically not very much either.

Comment: I find it useful for making a word bold or italic, instead of using a more complex GUI component. Just very basic HTML ..

Comment: Used it for that purpose too but quickly becomes a mess and is generally not very pleasant to work with. One of the many things Sun got somehow very wrong with Swing (imho) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can easily do that with a normal TextBox or Button. There are third party controls that might do that. WinForms is not a very extensible GUI framework at heart. If you are looking for that kind of capabilities, WPF is a great thing. WPF supports control composition and styling almost everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

For .Net you'll need to either use a RichTextbox control (and rtf formatting), embed a WebBrowser control, or inherit your own OwnerDrawn control from textbox.

I would be surprised if there aren't third-party controls out there that do that last option for you, but there's nothing "official" for this and you'll have to evaluate them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a WPF TextBlock (I think) control which has support for basic formatting *like* HTML (but not HTML tag themselves).